# Is the Covid-19 Vaccine the Mark of the Beast?

Tags: revelation, mark

I'm surprised this question hasn't been asked yet on this site.

Revelation 13:16-17:

> And he causeth all, both small and great, rich and poor, free and
> bond, to receive a mark in their right hand, or in their foreheads:
>
> And that no man might buy or sell, save he that had the mark, or the
> name of the beast, or the number of his name.

It seems that it has been issued to all people around the world. So it fits the description to some extent.

Comment: It hasn't been asked because it obviously isn't.

Comment: Not every poison is the mark and not every wicked genocidal man is the antichrist. We can call them so subjectively though in our context

Answer (score 3):

The previous verse, Revelation ch13 v15, says that the land-beast causes to be slain all those who would not "worship the image of" the sea-beast. Then v16 introduces the "mark" as the means of separating out those who will from those who won't. In other words, the mark identifies someone as willing to worship someone/something which is not the Creator God.

The Covid vaccine is not obviously doing anything of the kind. Nothing in the process makes the receiver conscious of choosing another god, And the choice would have to be conscious, because God would hardly need to punish the mark-wearers so fiercely (ch14 vv9-10) if they had been "tricked" into it, not knowing what they were doing. Therefore the vaccine cannot be the mark. The same observation applies, incidentally, to every other "mark" theory I've ever encountered. They are all designed to make people anxious about taking the mark accidentally.

I will now offer a method of identifying the mark which is guaranteed and foolproof, provided that the steps are taken in this order.

1. Identify the beast.
2. Find out what the beast is using to identify his followers.
3. That's your mark

The first step should be easy enough, because we know that the beast a) dominates the world (vv7-8) and b) uses this domination to pursue a powerful and murderous campaign against those who trust in God (v11). Can't see anyone around who fits both parts of the description? Then we don't have the beast yet, which means we won't see his mark either.

Comment: "*Nothing in the process makes the receiver conscious of choosing another god*". Not literally, although various behavioral patterns during the so-called "pandemic" present attributes typical of fanaticism, such as the belief in the omnipresence of a "virus", the rejection and ostracism of skeptics/dissenters of the official narrative, and a blind faith in salvation by getting injected.